# Elementary Matrix Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I suspect A and C to not be elementary matrices. However, I'm not sure which one. I'm simply confused regarding the diagonal placement in a) and c). Would you need more than 1 elementary row operation to achieve such matrices (A) and (c)?

EDIT: This was a careless mistake, I overlooked that row operations can be swapped.

Comment: "Elementary matrix" is a term with different definitions according to different authors. What is *your* definition ?

Comment: In my book, Elementary matrix is  an identity matrix that has been altered by a single row operation

Comment: Then your choice seems to be (c), as that matrix's the result of the identity matrix altered by **two** row operations

Comment: Yes, I also agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that swapping rows is an elementary row operation.  If you swap the first and third row of the identity matrix, you will get matrix A.